# Jquery simplemodal open dialog from link another dialog

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using the simplemodal Jquery API. just like the "Contact Form" modal sample in this link 
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

but I need to add another button or anchor tag like signup button from within the contact.php page and that button would open another php page content like signup.php. 
I have tried something like this see the link below:
http://at5024-lumooc.lakeheadu.ca/contact/

but the link does not open any dialog after...
I'm new to this so I need some help please....
this is the code I changed to the "Contact Form" demo
in the contact.php file I added this at the end of the ".contact-content" div

Open new Modal

you can see that clearly on the open dialog.
and on the contact.js

under the on show function I added this.

```
    $("#signup").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("The .... URL." + $(this).attr("href"));
        $.modal.close();
        $.modal(" I'm testing here");
    });
```

I can see the alert once the anchor is clicked and the current modal does close but I can't open a new modal. I have tried the last line with other ways like.

```
 $(" I'm testing here").modal();
```

and

```
 contact.init();
```

but no luck....

any idea any one... 
Thanks ahead...

Comment: You might need to destroy it like $("#dialog-divId").dialog('destroy').remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an order-of-operations issue, i.e. the modal closes after you try opening it. I'd suggest moving the line `$.modal(" I'm testing here");` into a function, and adding a call to it in the modal's `onClose` event.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked after I moved it to the onClose event I had to add a condition to confirm that it does not open every time it is in the close but that works now. Thank you